# Add hyperlink to d3.js table cells with dataset

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink

Suppose there's a given tab-separated values (TSV) file named *datatable.tsv*:

```
Title   URL DataChange
A   http://localhost/A.html 1
B   http://localhost/B.html -2
C   http://localhost/C.html 0
D   http://localhost/D.html 12
E   http://localhost/E.html -9
```

I need to generate a data table with D3.js and implement following requirements:

1. The first column displays a hyperlink with Title as text and URL as href.
2. The second column displays the DataChange value.
3. Digit values should be right aligned.
4. If the DataChange value is positive, set class "add"; otherwise set class "minus".

For my code as below, my questions are:

1. How can I add hyperlink to the first column?
2. Is there other method to improve the code for adding classes "right", "add" and "minus"?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Data Table</title>
    <style>
        table { border-collapse: collapse; color: #333; background-color: #F7F6F3; }
        table thead { font-weight: bold; background-color: #CCC; cursor: default; }
        table tbody tr:hover { background-color: #FFC; }
        td { border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 0 1ex; }
        .even { color: #284775; background-color: White; }
        .left { text-align: left; }
        .right { text-align: right; }
        .add { color: green; }
        .minus { color: red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="table"></div>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var table = d3.select("#table").append("table"),
            thead = table.append("thead"),
            tbody = table.append("tbody");
        thead.append("th").text("Title");
        thead.append("th").text("Data Change");

        d3.tsv("datatable.tsv", function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;
            var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("tr")
                .classed("even", function(d, i) { return i % 2 == 1; });
            var td = tr.selectAll("td")
                .data(function(d) { return [d.Title, d3.format("+")(+d.DataChange)]; })
                .enter().append("td")
                .text(function(d) { return d; })
                .classed("right", function(d, i) { return i == 1; })
                .classed("add", function(d, i) { return i == 1 && d.charAt(0) == "+"; })
                .classed("minus", function(d, i) { return i == 1 && d.charAt(0) == "-"; });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581272/d3-table-adding-specific-hyperlink-to-value) gave a solution using *selection.html*. But in my case the href reads from URL field and URL field should not be displayed in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like this:

```
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) {
        return [
            '<a href="'+d.URL+'">'+htmlencode(d.Title)+'</a>',
            d3.format("+")(+d.DataChange)
        ];
    })
    .enter().append("td")
    .html(function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
        return i == 1 ? "right " + (d.charAt(0) == "+" ? "add" : "minus") : null;
    });
```

I didn't understand the *selection.data* clearly enough when I asked this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using, the .each() function for each row to add the appropriate cells, like so:

```
  var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("tr")
      .classed("even", function(d, i) { return i % 2 == 1; });
  tr.each(function(d) {
    var self = d3.select(this);
    self
      .append("td")
      .append("a")
        .attr("href", d.URL)
        .text(d.Title);
    self.append("td")
        .html(d["Data Change"]);
  });
```

Here's a [working block](http://blockbuilder.org/seemantk/3368f8c9b3d896965879) you can play with.